# How to conditionally provide a style for a grid cell?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using the Kendo UI grid in my AngularJS application and I would wish to apply a certain background color conditionally. Below is my column definition :

```
columns: [
    { field: "TradeAmount", title: "Trade Amount", width: "120px", filterable: { cell: { showOperators: false } } },
]
```

So the above column is bound to the 'TradeAmount' field of the data source. Now I have another field named 'ApprovalStatus' in my data source which can have value as 'Approved' or 'Unapproved'. Based on this value I wish to change the background color for cells in the column; Green for Approved and Red for Unapproved.
Could someone help me out with that please.

Screenshot for @pankajparkar solution http://dojo.telerik.com/oREDI:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by using `template` option on field with `ng-style` directive.

```
columns: [
    { field: "TradeAmount", title: "Trade Amount", 
      width: "120px", filterable: { cell: { showOperators: false } }, 
      template: '<span ng-style="{background: #:ApprovalStatus# == \'Approved\'? \'red\': \'green\'}"></span>'
}]
```

Small [**Demo here**](http://dojo.telerik.com/abImO)

**Update**

For getting changes to be done on `td` element you need to apply it using the directive currently it is getting applied on the span which you are specifying in the templeate

```
.directive('setStyle', function() {
     return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.parent().css('backgroundColor', attrs.setStyle)
     }
})
```

Above directive will set `background-color` property inside `td` which is parent of specified template

**Template**

```
template: '<span set-style="#:FirstName == \'Nancy\'? \'red\': \'green\'#">#:FirstName#</span>',
```

[**Demo here**](http://dojo.telerik.com/EbEsi)

Comment: that didn't work...btw, where is the value comparison ?

Comment: inside ng-style i used #:ApprovalStatus# which will decide vale of background color

Comment: what if I want to have another ApprovalStatus with value 'Pending' ? And I am still unable to get your solution working

Comment: You need to ensure ApprovalStatus is in the context of cell template execution. You can add logging like: #console.log(ApprovalStatus)# and see if it is even present. For my purposes I managed to access other fields in the grid using data[field-name] (you can see what "data" contains using similar console.log call as above).

Comment: Yes, ApprovalStatus is in the context of cell template execution. The log is printing the ApprovalStatus value to the console.

Comment: @Lucifer take a look at the update code with telerik,,

Comment: @pankajparkar, I wish to have the background color for the cell, not text-highlighting.

Comment: @Lucifer then use `background-color` there

Comment: @pankajparkar, didn't work. could you please update the telerik link for this issue.

Comment: @pankajparkar, that still applies a background to the text, not the Cell (TD). I have updated my question with the screenshot.